# Partial Screen Hardware Accelerated Video

Tags: android, video, hardware-acceleration

I am working on a honeycomb tablet application which renders beneath and on top of a partial-screen video (think 300x400 video inside a tablet screen.) This works fine when using full software rendering. However, when enabling hardware acceleration and playing a video using a videoview, all I see is a black screen with the video where it should be. I tried writing a custom view using a surfaceview and the media player, but that didn't work either. Is this just a limitation of using hardware acceleration?